# How to pass parameter programmatically to Azure Data Factory Pipeline through Azure Function from C# code?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I want to pass the output parameter to the Azure Data factory Pipeline.

eg. I have parameter like this

`pipelineparameter:`
`{`
`"emp_id":1,`
`"emp_name": "Havells",`
`"emp_dept":"IT"`
`}`

The code is as below..

`{`
`CreateRunResponse runResponse;`
`PipelineRun pipelineRun;`
`runResponse = client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(`
`resourceGroup, factoryName, pipelineName, parameters: (IDictionary<string, object>)parameters).Result.Body;`

`}`

When I tried to read that parameter like the below manner
`'pipelineRun.Parameters'`
then it gives me an error like this: `` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String] ``

Comment: Question is not clear, can you please be specific about what you are trying to do and background around it and then possible share the minimum possible code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use in my Azure Function:

```
public async Task<string> RunPipelineAsync(string resourceGroupName,
                                                   string dataFactoryName,
                                                   string pipelineName,
                                                   Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null,
                                                   Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders = null)
        {
            var runResponse = await Client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName, pipelineName, parameters: parameters , customHeaders: customHeaders);
            return runResponse.Body.RunId;
        }
```

Without being able to see your entire error message, my assumption is that the object *parameters* is failing to cast to *IDictionary<string, object>*.